# Why is there delay when I write on a file using c++?

Tags: c++

I've tried to open a file, write something on it, read from the file and do the same process again but the output isn't what I expect, here's the code:

```
    file.open("ciao.txt", std::ios::out);
    file << "ciao";
    file.close();

    file.open("ciao.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
    std::string str;
    std::getline(file, str);
    cout << str;
    file.seekp(0);
    file << "addio";
    std::getline(file, str);
    cout << str;
```

The expected oputput is "ciao addio", but it only gives me "ciao". I've tried to run it line after line, but the file is edited as soon as the program stops. Can someone help please? I couldn't find anything online ;-;

Comment: you should try both flushing and resetting the get pointer. Maybe `file << "addio"; file.flush(); file.seekg(0); std::getline(file, str);` will do the trick

Comment: @PeterT thanks, but now I get "ciao ciao" as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a combination of things.

Here you write `ciao` to the file, no problem - except it doesn't have a newline (`\n`).

```
file << "ciao";
```

Later, you read a line:

```
std::getline(file, str);
```

Had there been a `\n` in the file, `EOF` would not have been reached and the `fstream` would still be in good shape for accepting I/O. Now it's not however.

So, either `file.clear()` after the `getline` or add a newline to the first output:

```
file << "ciao\n";
```

You also need to `file.seekg(0);` before the last `getline`.

```cpp
file.open("ciao.txt", std::ios::out);
file << "ciao";
file.close();

file.open("ciao.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
std::string str;
std::getline(file, str);
file.clear();               // add this
cout << str;
file.seekp(0);
file << "addio";
file.seekg(0);              // add this
std::getline(file, str);

// I added > and < to make it clear what comes from the file:
cout << '>' << str << "<\n";
```

Output:

```
ciao>addio<
```